# How to calculate difference between two periods values in Tableau Desktop

Tags: tableau-api

In Tableau Desktop, I have 2 different periods as per below:
[image]

and I want the result to be 20 --> Value (29) - Value (28) = 20

Thank you,

Comment: Are periods date fields? How does 29 - 28 = 20?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a calculated field `calculated_value` and compute using 'Table (down)'.

```
sum(Value) - lookup(sum([Value]), -1)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue I was trying to resolve and managed to use parameters for added flexibility.

The calculation by Prem only gives you the difference based on the previous value.

In case you wanted it to be adjusted between different periods. You can use parameters to help with this.

---

Make Period a 'Date' datatype and create 2 parameters:

Params (Start Date/End Date): Type 'Data', List and pull values from Field 'Period'

Create a calculated field called 'Numerator': if([Period] = [Start Date]) Then [Value] else 0 end

Create a calculated field called 'Denominator: if([Period] = [End Date]) Then [Value] else 0 end

Create a calculated field called '%Difference': Sum([Denominator])-Sum([Numerator])

This gives flexibility for different periods and allows users to toggle which value they want and to see the difference accordingly.

---

Alternatively, you can see a link I found helpful as well: https://community.tableau.com/thread/225030